# SVG Path : How to marker-end arrow head to circle border?

Tags: svg

I making circle (about Radian to 20). and have a few text on inside.
and I want to draw arrow-path to it.
So I use "marker-end" .  but circle override arrow.
How to (Can I ) move marker-end location to circle border?

```html
<svg width="600px" height="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">


<defs><!-- ready for endpoint arrow -->
<marker id="endpoint" viewBox="-50 0 50 50" refX="0" refY="25" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20" orient="auto">
  <path d="M -50 0 L 0 25 L -50 50 z"></path>
</marker>
</defs>
  
<g>
<text x="10" y="50">Trouble : Arrow Hide(override) by Circle</text>
<path d="M 0,100 C 50,100 80,131 130,131 C 130,131 190,130 200,100" 
        stroke="black" fill="none" marker-end="url(#endpoint)"></path>
  <path d="M 440,100 C 350,100 350,131 300,131 C 260,131 230,60 200,100"
        stroke="black" fill="none" marker-end="url(#endpoint)"></path>
 <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="20" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#aaa" fill="#fff" opacity="0.95"></circle>
<text x="165" y="105">Some Text</text>
 </g>
 <g>
 <text x="10" y="240">What I want?</text>
 <text x="10" y="260">Auto detect arrow head to border</text>
<path d="M 0,300 C 50,300 80,331 130,331 C 130,331 180,330 200,300" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
<path d="M 185 315 L 174 312 L 185 326 z"></path>
   
   
<path d="M 440,300 C 350,300 350,331 300,331 C 260,331 230,260 200,300" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
<path d="M 216 289 L 223 295 L 220 283 z"></path>
 
 <circle cx="200" cy="300" r="20" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#aaa" fill="#fff" opacity="0.75"></circle>
 <text x="165" y="305">Some Text</text>
 </g>
 <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have markers be drawn back along the line away from the end.

You wither need to draw the arrow heads yourself.  Or have the lines end at the circle border.

Comment: oh... noway...okay I will try to other way.

Comment: well there is a marker-mid property which will draw a marker at an intermediate vertex - if you chop your path into two subpaths, you can use this to put a marker at an intermediate position

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone.I try another way.
Example.

```js
var draw = function(type, opts) {
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
  for (var k in opts) {
    svg.setAttribute(k, opts[k]);
  }
  return svg;
};


var getCircleDestination = function(from, to) {

  var tx = parseFloat(to.getAttribute("cx"));
  var ty = parseFloat(to.getAttribute("cy"));

  var fx = from.center.x;
  var fy = from.center.y;

  var w = fx - tx;
  var h = fy - ty;

  var z = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
  var r = parseFloat(to.getAttribute("r"));

  var dz = z / r;

  var dx = tx + w / dz;
  var dy = ty + h / dz;

/* dx2,dy2 ...dz * 1.2 is no good idea. */
  var dx2 = tx + w / (dz * 1.2); 
  var dy2 = ty + h / (dz * 1.2);

  var circle = draw("circle", {
    "cx": dx,
    "cy": dy,
    "r": 3,
    "fill": "red"
  });

  return {
    "s": {
      "x": dx2,
      "y": dy2
    },
    "svg": circle
  };
};





var canvas = draw("svg", {
  "width": "400",
  "height": "150",
  "style": "background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid black;"
});
var def = draw("defs", {});
var marker = draw("marker", {
  "id": "endpoint",
  "viewBox": "-50 0 50 50",
  "refX": 0,
  "refY": 25,
  "markerUnits": "strokeWidth",
  "markerWidth": 10,
  "markerHeight": 10,
  "orient": "auto"
});
var marker_path = draw("path", {
  "d": "M -50 0 L 0 25 L -50 50 z"
});
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.style.display = "block";
btn.innerHTML = "Add Line";

canvas.appendChild(def);
canvas.appendChild(marker);
marker.appendChild(marker_path);

document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(canvas);
document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(btn);

var circle = draw("circle", {
  "cx": 200,
  "cy": 75,
  "r": 10,
  "fill": "white",
  "stroke": "black",
  "stroke-width": 1,
  "opacity": 0.5
});
canvas.appendChild(circle);

var paths = new Array();
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x = Math.random() * canvas.clientWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * canvas.clientHeight;
  var from = {
    "center": {
      "x": x,
      "y": y
    }
  };

  var svg = getCircleDestination(from, circle);
  var c = svg.svg;
  var stx = svg.s.x;
  var sty = svg.s.y;

  var ttx = svg.s.x + (Math.random() * 10 + 15) * (svg.s.x < x ? 1 : -1);
  var tty = svg.s.y + (Math.random() * 10 + 15) * (svg.s.y < y ? 1 : -1);

  var p = draw("path", {
    "d": "M" + x + "," + y + " Q " + ttx + "," + tty + " " + stx + "," + sty + " " + c.getAttribute("cx") + "," + c.getAttribute("cy"),
    "stroke": "black",
    "fill": "none",
    "marker-end": "url(#endpoint)"
  });


  canvas.appendChild(c);
  canvas.appendChild(p);
  paths.push({
    "c": c,
    "p": p
  });
  if (paths.length > 5) {
    var t = paths.shift();
    t.c.remove();
    t.p.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```